# input value not increasing in this code, function calling itself with 0 value?

Tags: java, recursion

Everytime func calls itself with 0 value, i's value is not increasing.

```
int f(n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += f(n-i);//func calls itself and everytime i is 0
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit what do wanna achieve from the provided code?

Comment: I want to find out the branching factor and I read it somewhere that it's n in this case and I don't know how because.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is executing an infinite loop.
Let's consider that you call `f` with the value `15` for `n`.
Then the function will call `f(15)` again (because you start your loop at `i=0` and because `15-0=15`).
As we saw above, calling `f(15)` calls .... `f(15)`, which calls `f(15)`, and so on.

A solution (I don't know what is the *purpose* of your code) would be to initialize the value of `i` in the loop to `1`. Then at least you would not be stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wanna get the output as the sum from 1 to till passed input, if yes then try below code:

```
public static int fun(int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return n + fun(n - 1);
}
```